# TinyMCE.Mvc.Jquery do not displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

i have a problem in my project with html editor displaying.

http://postimg.org/image/3xd9cpja7/

http://postimg.org/image/m1g9xcgyn/

**I installed it from Nuget Manager:** 1 image

**then i added atributes to my model:** 3 image

**Prices View Model:** 2 image

**In _AdminRoomLayout I added jquery....js** 5 image

**My solution:** 4 image

I use model(Price) from Data project in WebStudio project.
All data shown correct except editor.
Can anybody help me with TinyMCE editor, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add tinymce downloaded folder to your project
You can download it from [Here](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php) and if you want the below code to run properly than you need to download TinyMCE 3.5.11 version.

After adding the folder add the java script path reference at the head

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

like this.

than you need to add the script to call your text area with tinymce

```
 tinyMCE.init({

                // General options
                mode: "exact",
                elements: "<%=YourTextAreaId.ClientID %>",
                theme: "advanced",
                plugins: "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave,visualblocks",

                // Theme options
                theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
                theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,visualblocks",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
                theme_advanced_resizing: true,

                // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
                content_css: "css/content.css",

                // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
                template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
                external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
                external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
                media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",

                // Style formats
                style_formats: [
        { title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b' },
        { title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#ff0000' } },
        { title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: { color: '#ff0000' } },
        { title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1' },
        { title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2' },
        { title: 'Table styles' },
        { title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1' }
                ],

                // Replace values for the template plugin
                template_replace_values: {
                    username: "Some User",
                    staffid: "991234"
                }
            });
```

Comment: But i did all this stuff diffrent way - from Nuget.

Comment: Have you tried my code. Its fine with nuget but you need to initialize the text area and this is how you initialize it I had done this way and it is working fine in my project.

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thank you, I will use tinyMCE this way. Thanks a lot!